# AWS S3 file upload with Node.js: Unsupported body payload error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backend

I am trying to get my node.js backend to upload a file to AWS S3, which it got in a post request from my front-end. This is what my function looks like:

```
async function uploadFile(file){

  var uploadParams = {Bucket: '<bucket-name>', Key: file.name, Body: file};

  s3.upload (uploadParams, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } if (data) {
      console.log("Upload Success", data.Location);
    }
  });

}
```

When I try uploading the file this way, I get an Unsupported Body Payload Error...

I used fileStream.createReadStream() in the past to upload files saves in a directory on the server, but creating a fileStream did not work for me, since there is no path parameter to pass here.

EDIT:
The file object is created in the angular frontend of my web application. This it the relevant html code where the file is uploaded by a user:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="file">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file" id="file"(change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

If the event occurs, the `handleFileInput(files: FileList)` method in the corresponding component is called:

```
  handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    // should result in array in case multiple files are uploaded
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    // actually upload the file
    this.uploadFileToActivity();
    // used to check whether we really received the file
    console.log(this.fileToUpload);
    console.log(typeof this.fileToUpload)
  }

  uploadFileToActivity() {
    this.fileUploadService.postFile(this.fileToUpload).subscribe(data => {
      // do something, if upload success
      }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

the `postFile(fileToUpload: File)` method of the file-upload service is used to make the post request:

```
  postFile(fileToUpload: File): Observable<Boolean> {
    console.log(fileToUpload.name);
    const endpoint = '/api/fileupload/single';
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this.httpClient
      .post(endpoint, formData/*, { headers: yourHeadersConfig }*/)
      .pipe(
        map(() => { return true; }),
        catchError((e) => this.handleError(e)),
      );
  }
```

Here is the the server-side code that receives the file and then calls the `uploadFile(file)` function:

```
  app.post('/api/fileupload/single', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if(!req.files) {
            res.send({
                status: false,
                message: 'No file uploaded'
            });
        } else {

            let file = req.files.fileKey;
            uploadFile(file);

            //send response
            res.send({
                status: true,
                message: 'File is uploaded',
                data: {
                    name: file.name,
                    mimetype: file.mimetype,
                    size: file.size
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
  });
```

Thank you very much for your help in solving this!

Best regards, Samuel

Comment: Body needs to be a Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, or ReadableStream. What type is it?

Comment: @jarmod When I log the datatype using `typeof` I get the log: `object`. The file I originally uploaded is a .pdf if that matters. I tried converting the file to type Buffer using: `Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(file), 'utf-8')` but that did not work for me. Thank you for your help!

Comment: How are you creating the `file` object? Can you add that code?

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for your quick response. I edited my question and included the code. Best regards!

Comment: You've shown the client-side code but it's the server-side code that's key. The code that receives the posted file and then supplies each file to your 'upload to S3' function. What are you doing server-side to accept the uploaded file? For example you could have middleware that persists it to disk, or you may be using Express that passes the file content to you in a specific format.

Comment: @jarmod I have included the server-side code in my question now as well - thank you for helping me! left the front end code in place in case it is helpful

Comment: Problem is that we still have no idea what software you are using. Are you using Express? Are you using middleware such as body-parser? Try to work out what `req.files` is. It's presumably an array (because it's name is plural) so it's likely that you have to use `req.files[0].something` to access the first (only?) uploaded file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is stream the file. Assuming you are. reading it from disk. You could do this

```
const fs = require("fs");
const aws = require("aws-sdk");
const s3Client = new aws.S3();
const Bucket = 'somebucket';
const stream = fs.createReadStream("file.pdf");
const Key = stream.path;

const response = await s3Client.upload({Bucket, Key, Body: stream}).promise();
console.log(response);
```

Comment: I am not reading the file from the disk. I am working on a web application and users upload their files in the angular frontend - then the files get posted to the backend which should upload them. Could on create a stream in the frontend and pass it to backend?